# Selecting data from database based on selection from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Newby to php / sql so be kind to my ignorance.

On page index.php I have a navigation menu that retrieves options from table car_category, column car_type. 
If user selects option from navigation, it takes him to another page where he should see list of entries selected from column car_review_details, coming from another table, car_review.

First function executes on index.php and retrieves the data from table car_category:

```
function list_type (){
        global $conn, $sql, $test;
        $test = "SELECT car_type FROM `car_category` WHERE car_type IS NOT NULL AND car_type <> ''";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $test);
            if (!$result){
                die("failed");
            }
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<a href='car_review.php?subject=";
                echo urlencode ($row["car_type"]);
                echo "'>";
                echo $row ["car_type"];
                echo "</a>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
    }
```

The function above works fine.

Now, on page care_review.php I would like display the data from column car_review_details. The tables car_category and car_review have the column catID which should determine which data gets selected from table car_review, based on the selected link in page index.php

Code for function on page car_review.php looks as following:

```
function car_style(){
        global $conn;
        $details = "SELECT *
                    FROM `car_category`
                    INNER JOIN `car_review`
                    ON `car_category`.`catID` = `car_review`.`catID`
                    WHERE `car_category`.`catID` = $row ['catDesc']";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $details);
            if (!$result){
                die("failed");
            }              
            while ($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo ($row_1["car_review_details"]);
                echo  "<br>";              
            } 
    }
```

How do I go about echoing data from column car_review_details based on selection from function list_type ().

Many thanks for your feedback.

Comment: what you really need is a SQL JOIN

Comment: that didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: "didn't work","there was an error", etc are statements that are not very usefull.